# Ajax requests are really slow in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I started developing in Laravel lately and I want to build a simple webshop. For some functionalities I want to use Ajax for the better experience.

I made an Add to cart button on every product page. It sends the product id (and the CSRF token too) to the controller, which sends back only a text. This request takes up to 2-300ms, which is really bad. (I use livewire too and it takes another 200ms to update the cart counter.)
**Is this slow Ajax because of the speed of my development environment and my internet?** I tested it on an other slower machine and the ajax queries were 4-500ms. If I would deploy my app on a web hosting, like namecheap, would it be faster?

My addToCart function (I know this should be more, but now I reduced it to not waste any time in this function.)

```php
public function addToCart(Request $request) {
        return array('old' => "ok");
}
```

The form in my blade.php:

```html
<form id="buyForm" action="{{ route('addToCart') }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <input name="id" type="text" hidden value="{{ $product['id'] }}">
                <button class="add-to-cart mt-3 w-100">
                    Add to cart
                </button>
            </form>
```

And the submit function:

```js
$('#buyForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: '../addToCart',
           data: $('#buyForm').serialize(),
           success: function(data)
           {
               console.log(data);
               Livewire.emit('updateCart')
           }
         });
    })
```

Comment: Are you possibly using docker?

Comment: No, I don't use any containerized environment. i just simply serve it with 'php artisan serve'.

Comment: Can you share both ajax request and the controller method please?

Comment: Share the code, no one can help you if nothing is shared!

Comment: Yes, sorry, I updated my question!

Comment: Wild guess: it's this part of the code `Livewire.emit('updateCart')` that is slowing down the page.

Comment: I tried to remove it, but the Ajax requests still taked up 200-300ms. On a normal webshop, it fires in 100ms.

Comment: I think you have to use indexed data if you do any query on database in ajax request.